# HP ProLiant Smart Array "lock up" code 0x11

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, hp-smart-array

I've a ProLiant DL580 G7 server that experienced a storage subsystem failure during production. The system appeared available and responded to pings, but all I/O access stalled (the system load must have been 100+). The ASR did not trigger at the specified watchdog timeout. I had to force a reboot from the ILO. During POST, I received the following error:

`A controller failure event occurred prior to this power-up. (Previous lock up code = 0x11)`

I haven't pulled the ADU report yet, but I'm curious as to what this error actually means. I was not responsible for the the installation, but can see that the firmware is very old. But if there's anything else I should know about the error, I'd like to know for the post-mortem report.

***Edit*** - I should add that the server had 95 days of uptime prior to the lock up.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [this advisory](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/Document.jsp?objectID=c02910003&jumpid=em_alerts_us-us_Jul11_xbu_all_all_1338480_90722_proliantserversbladesystemstorageoptionsandaccessoriesintegrityservers_critical_000_0) which suggests that such an error requires a firmware upgrade for the SmartArray controller in question.

(Disclaimer: I'm a HP employee but not in storage, sales or support, I just have some hardware displaying the same error).

Comment: This led me to a better solution. I still think that something at the OS level is aggravating the controller, but firmware is a potential issue.

Answer (score 3):

HP doesn't publish what the lock up codes mean. In my experience they always result in some hardware needing to be replaced. You'll have to pull the ADU and submit it to HP support.

Comment: Couldn't agree more Chris, this looks like either a suspect controller or possibly an issue with the FBWC, either way get HP to replace BOTH the controller and the cache.

Comment: Definitely a bad sign, time to get support involved.

Comment: Given that the uptime was 90+ days from initial installation, does this just seem like a premature failure of the component? I'm the thousands of HP servers I've deployed, I've only seen something like this twice. I was hoping we could get specifics on the meaning of the error code.

Comment: Definitely premature failure. If you can get the meaning of the code out of HP I'd be really impressed. For whatever reason they've been tight lipped on those lock-up codes.